# Using the 'past tense' versus 'past perfect' - Apostrophes

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, apostrophe

When we are talking about the past actions in general; past tense, or a combination of past, and past perfect is more desirable?

1. Alt. 1

Since the symbolic buildings are the first things that come to our minds upon hearing the name of a city, **those who made war** throughout history , **always went** after destroying them to destroy the spirit of place.

1. Alt. 2

Since the symbolic buildings are the first things that come to our minds upon hearing the name of a city, **those who made war** throughout history , **had always gone** after destroying them to destroy the spirit of place.

Also 'the name of a city', or 'a city's name' ? which one is better in this sentence?

Thanks
BM

Comment: I would vote for the first one.

Comment: We're not supposed to give writing advice here, but I would suggest that, as this tendency is an ongoing one, you might use **those who have made war...have always gone**.

Comment: "Had always gone" sounds as though warmakers have ceased destroying the symbolic buildings, so I agree with @RamPillai.  I have no preference between 'the name of a city' and 'a city's name'.